# How to prevent users from resizing the font on my web site?

Tags: fonts, accessibility

How to prevent users from resizing the font on my web site?

Comment: What is the problem that you want to do that?

Comment: @Vainstah ... upvote him then :)

Comment: Those pesky users. Always with the wanting to make stuff easier to read...

Comment: Use images and get lost from Google's index. (And estimated 0 persons will miss the page there.)

Comment: Images can be resized as well in any modern browser.

Comment: -6?  must be a good question to have invoked so much passion :)  ... there are benevolent reasons why he'd want to do this.  we did this, detected resize, then offered the user an alternative site if they wanted it.  I posted that solution below.

Comment: Have you thought about how you are going to stop people from moving their head closer to the screen, even if you keep font size the same, which would give the appearance of a larger font?

Answer (score 45):

In fact, you should allow font resizing for accessibility reasons.

Comment: haughty and unnecessarily curt without providing the "why?" says man with 67 pts to SO God with 43k

Answer (score 26):

You can't. Font resizing takes place on the client side over which you simply have no control. Users are free to increase or decrease the font size as they please.

If you're worried about your page markup breaking at bigger font sizes, then simply ignore it. There is no way to create a more or less sophisticated design resilient to any possible font size variation. And if the user chooses to play around with it, then it's ultimately their fault if the markup breaks. But they are likely accustomed to seeing broken pages already.

Anyway, modern versions of browsers (IE, FireFox, Opera) simply scale the rendered page leaving relative proportions of elements intact. The problem is solved.

Comment: modern browsers usually provide for both - zooming with font and without.  And <IE7 only provides for increasing text size.

Plus you do have control over what takes place on the client side.  Font resize detection (and thus compensating for font resize detection) is a perfectly valid option.  I posted a solution below that does exactly that.  PS. I love Stuttgart!!

Answer (score 20):

Two options:

1. Make all your text into images.
2. Detect browser font size changes and base font (when they arrive at your site), then adjust the font size dynamically to compensate for their change.

Here's the javascript for the font-size detector: http://www.alistapart.com/d/fontresizing/textresizedetector.js

And now all you have to do is attach a resize function to the listener and surround all your markup in a div with id, "bodyContent" (that way the font event listener won't catch your compensation functions:

```
addFontResizeListener = function () {
        var iBase, reloadBoolean;

        iBase = addEventListener(lzaIndex.onFontResize, null);

        //Don't run the updateBaseFontSize if font size is not larger than usual
        if (iBase > 20) {
            reloadBoolean = false;
            updateBaseFontSize(iBase, reloadBoolean);
        }
    };

    //id of element to check for and insert control
    TextResizeDetector.TARGET_ELEMENT_ID = 'bodyContent';
    //function to call once TextResizeDetector has init'd
    TextResizeDetector.USER_INIT_FUNC = addFontResizeListener;

    onFontResize = function (e, args) {
        var iSize, reloadBoolean;

        iSize = args[0].iSize; //get new user defined size

        reloadBoolean = true;
        updateBaseFontSize(iSize, reloadBoolean);
    };
```

Then add the readjustment itself:

```
updateBaseFontSize : function (fontSize, reloadBool) {
    /*Format 1 is fed from the plugin; format2 is the body size equiv
     *examples:
     *Frmt 1 (all/IE) | Frmt 2 (all/IE)
     *20/18           | 16px/16px
     *21/21           | 17.6px/19px
     *22/23           | 19.2px/22px
     *
     *Purpose of updateBaseFontSize is:
     * 1. convert format 1 figures to format 2
     * 2. modify the all containing div 'fontbodyreadjust'
     *    to compensate for the new user defined body font size
     */


    var format1Base, format1Size, reloadPage, baseConverter, changeConverter,
    format2Base, format2SizeChange, format2NewSize, modifiedSize;

    format1Size = fontSize; //equals new size in pixels
    reloadPage = reloadBool; //prevents reload on 1st visit

    if ($('body').hasClass('browserIE')) {
        format1Base = 19; //expected base size value for IE
        baseConverter = 16 / 19; //converts from format 1 to 2 for IE
        changeConverter = 1.5; //ditto for the difference from base size for IE
    } else {
        format1Base = 20;//expected base size value for all other browsers
        baseConverter = 16 / 20; //converts from format 1 to 2 for all others
        changeConverter = 1.6; //ditto for the difference from base size for all others
    }

    //Find modifiedSize, how much to compensate for the new body size
    format2Base = format1Base * baseConverter;

    format2SizeChange = (format1Size - format1Base) * changeConverter;
    format2NewSize = format2SizeChange + format2Base;

    modifiedSize = format2Base / format2NewSize;

    //Allow text resizing for shrinking text and very very large text
    //Only works for safari. meant to prevent odd behavior at math extremes
    jFontBodyReadjust = $('#fontbodyreadjust');

    if ((format2NewSize >= format2Base) && (modifiedSize > 0.6)) {
        jFontBodyReadjust.css('font-size', modifiedSize + 'em');
    }

    //reloadPage boolean in place so that reload doesn't occur on first visit
    if (reloadPage) {
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

REMEMBER: Provide an alternative to those who can't see your defined font size.  It's the right thing to do.  You can put access to your alternative (e.g., via a pop-up question) within the `if (iBase > 20)`

PS. Also remember you can specify ALL of your element widths (images, etc.) in ems so that font resize adjusts everything, BUT it's a bit messy, there are different browser interpretations that must be compensated for, and you can't use sprites (because ems would just show more of the sprite subsection that you want.

PSS. Specifying in px won't do you any good on modern browsers...don't know why that seems to be a popular answer here.

Answer (score 18):

what about converting your text to image.

Comment: And what about accessibility?

Comment: This is a good answer to the question, it's just a bad question to begin with.

Comment: +1 it is a solution. Using a plugin content or image is the only way to prevent it.

Comment: This is a great answer for the question, so why the down-votes?

Comment: @lewap: downvoted for the same reason that a "great answer" to the question "How can I murder my neighbour?" would, by definition, be a bad answer.

Comment: I didn't agree with the original question as it's not good for accessibility for sure ,but I just try to help him out.

Answer (score 8):

Publish as PDF. As others have said, HTML was not designed as a print medium

Answer (score 4):

Technically you cant, but what you can do is:

1. Recreate everything into flash site
2. Disable zoom-in, or right-click menu when embed your flash to your site. (just google how to disable the right-click menu, very easy, something like, "allow-menu=false"

Thats it. MOST of users cant resize the font now, unless they know how to hack =)

Do it, if you:
1. Have lots of time
2. Want to experiment new things
3. Dont mind waste your time and energy (lol)

Answer (score 4):

While generally a bad idea, the situation is not as clear cut as previously mentioned.

As of now (Sep 2012), it currently is possible to prevent users of **Google Chrome** and **Safari** from resizing the rendered font. The method below, is provided for the sake of completeness, and to raise awareness. Please avoid the temptation to utilize this folks, as it seriously breaks usability and accessibility guidelines.

```css
p {
     -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
  }
```

As per this [Mozzila discussion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-size-adjust), the extension was intended for mobile, but it unfortunately worked its way into the [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/) powered desktop browsers.

It is non-standard, and hence a prefix must be used. The corresponding extensions for Firefox and IE, `-moz-text-size-adjust` and `-ms-text-size-adjust`, are appropriately behaved.

Additionally, there is a [WebKit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=56543) logged regarding the issue.

---

*Example:*

There has been horrible abuse of this, on a number of sites. [Facebook's Social plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/), is one such case.

- [FB comments on Techcrunch](https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D11%23cb%3Df14c17a4b4%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Ftechcrunch.com%252Ff3df2f9f1c%26domain%3Dtechcrunch.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&href=http%3A%2F%2Ftechcrunch.com%2F2012%2F08%2F31%2Fopen-compute-project-can-facebook-help-save-the-world%2F&locale=en_US&numposts=25&sdk=joey&width=630)

Viewing the above link, in Safari or Chrome, will currently not allow resizing via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> <sub>[Lin/Win]</sub> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><sub>[OS X]</sub>

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. Browser's "zoom" controls are not in the power of the developer to adjust. Besides, the "font" will be different based on different screen resolutions (if your font size is in pixels, for example).

Answer (score 3):

Its the law in the UK that you should not provide a website/service that restricsts access to those with disabilities.

> From 1st October 1999 a service provider has to take reasonable steps to change a practice which makes it unreasonably difficult for disabled people to make use of its services

[Disabilty Act](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/web-accessibility/uk-website-legal-requirements.shtml)

Although this law is not enforced, it is seen as "The Code of Practice which specifically mentions websites".

Its only a 'code of practice', and not everyone follows it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you *really* want is to keep the image-text-ratio as it is, because your customer insists that the user gets a consistent, fixed layout (even though you tried to tell him that this is not how the web works).

In that case, an easy workaround is to specify font sizes in `px` units in CSS. That way, the user will still be able to use the zoom function of his browser, but the relationship of your 15px font to your 150px image will always be constant, independent of the user's font size or dpi settings.

Comment: Isn't it better to do all measurements in em?

Comment: Specifying image sizes in `em` will cause them to scale, even if the user does not use the zoom function. This might negatively affect the perceived image quality.

Answer (score 1):

Specify font sizes in pixels.  I don't recommend it though.