# Div resizing / adapting

Tags: html, css, menu, resize, responsive-design

I'm having a problem and can't seem to go around it.

Basically I want my menu and my text to resize with resolution change / zoom in/out; images work fine, content divs work fine, just the menu seems impossible to adapt.

Please help me with this..

Normal view: http://s17.postimg.org/ngj8k0skv/norm.jpg

Zoomed view:

http://s17.postimg.org/p729lia3z/notnorm.jpg

The menu looks like this:

```
<a href="nissan-s13-project.html" title="The Project">The Project<span class="desc">Full description</span></a>
```

and the CSS for this is

```
a .desc {
    display: none;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-size: 1em%;
    color: #FC0;
    max-width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

a:hover .desc, .active .desc {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    max-width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I really don't know what else to do..

Oh, and the text is like:

```
#content p {
    margin: 1.2em 1.2em 2em 1.2em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need your text not to resize on zoom. But that is difficult to get, and not user friendly (if somebody want to resize a page is likely because he needs a bigger text). 
Read here why: [How to prevent users from resizing the font on my web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831922/how-to-prevent-users-from-resizing-the-font-on-my-web-site)

Comment: Yes, but zooming in breaks the design of the most of the web sites and the users usally know that. Anyway try to remove the #content p{max-width:100%;}. That should allow the p to go beyond the window size. If it's not working try to remove other max-width or width : 100% of the containers of the menu.